# Find all the substrings of the string $aabaabb$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find all the substrings of the string $aabaabb$

Can anyone give me tips to this question and the methods used to determine the substring?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what "substring" means?

Comment: @Fundamental I'm having trouble making application of what I think it means.

Comment: @natur3 what do you think it means?

Comment: @Sanjab I belive it means that it is a "sub" set of the entire string $aabaabb$ or that it contains one or more combinations of these characters. Given that its not a set or ordered pair I cant determine from my book how to start counting the substrings.

Comment: @natur3 yes correct, subset of the string. but characters stay together (eg. ac is not a substring of abc, but ab is). Start by finding all substrings of length 1, then all of length 2 and so on ...

Comment: @sanjab so like this:

$$a,a,b,ab,a,b,b$$
$$aa,aab,ab$$

Comment: @natur3 note that substrings that are the same word can be listed once: $$a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, aab, aba, \ldots$$

Comment: @sanjab I'm going to try and walk through your steps and see if I can get the same thing. Thanks btw.

Comment: @sanjab So we are counting from left to right 1) unique strings in the entire set, 2) then doubles of the same character so far?

Comment: @natur3 no just think of finding subwords of length 1, 2, 3 and so on. maybe this makes it more clear: $$\require{cancel}a\cancel{abaabb}, \cancel{a}a\cancel{baabb}, \cancel{aa}b\cancel{aabb}, \ldots$$

Comment: @sanjab thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \epsilon $$
$$a, b$$
$$ aa, ab, ba, bb$$
$$aab, aba, baa, abb$$
$$aaba, abaa, baab, aabb$$
$$aabaa, abaab, baabb$$
$$aabaab, abaabb$$
$$aabaabb$$